# How to do Page-Up on a Mac in Terminal

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, bash, terminal

The laptop has no page-up/down buttons. How can I have page-up/down on the terminal, e.g. when I edit with vi?

Answer (score 56):

On Snow Leopard on MacBook, I use <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>down</kbd> to page up and down respectively on the terminal. And when inside an editor, such as Vim, I hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key in addition to the mentioned key combinations to page up and down within the editor.

Comment: shift + FN + (Up arrow or Down arrow) works for me. Thanks sooo much for this post. I was going nuts trying to get page up to work in a terminal on my mac.

Comment: It would be awesome if there were a one-handed form of these keys... it's awkward having to use two hands when scrolling up and down (most laptops don't have a Function key on the right hand side, near the arrow keys).

Comment: Did not work for me (2017). see answer

Comment: Use Cmd + fn + up

Comment: If you use iterm you can change the key combo for Page Up/Page Down to just use the Page Up/Down keys without also having to press a modifier like fn or Ctrl.

Comment: This is just scrolling up. It is supposed to search the history.

Answer (score 26):

Use <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> (forward) for page down, and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> (backward) for page down.

Comment: Perfect. Obviously, the accepted answer doesn't work if you have a macbook with no up/down keys.

Comment: @Xeoncross MacBook without up/down keys? I don't think such thing exists.

Answer (score 3):

In 2017 macOS Sierra 10.12 I had to use these:

> - **Page UP/DOWN:**
>
>   - up <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>up</kbd>
>   - down <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>down</kbd>

moreover, these are also useful:

- **marking:** (inputs can be marked automatically; fuzzy for long output)

  - set <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>
  - unset <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>
  - previous <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>up</kbd>
  - next <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>down</kbd>
- **bookmarks**

  - set <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>
  - previous <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>up</kbd>
  - next <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>down</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Generally on the Macbook page up and page down are a key combination. On current Macbooks Page Up is the <kbd>FN</kbd> (function) key (at the bottom left of the keyboard) and up arrow. Page down is <kbd>FN</kbd> key and down arrow. On some older macbooks I believe you need to use the 'Apple' key (which is located in roughly the same place as the Windows key on a PC keyboard) instead.