# Keyboard shortcut to scroll Terminal one line at a time

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app

I'm using Terminal on OS X El Capitan. I want to scroll my terminal output by lines (not using page-up or down). I'm pretty sure I used to do this with Cmd-up/Cmd-down, but now that appears to just cycle through (and highlight) previous prompts.

Any idea how to get the old functionality back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the *View* menu, it has bindings for *Line up* and *Line down*, but no help for the icons.

I do not have a Mac keyboard, so there are no icons "at hand".

However, those icons are shown in [Terminal Keyboard Shortcuts](http://mac.keyboard-shortcuts.eu/en/terminal/), allowing me to see that the binding is

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PageUp</kbd> and
 <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PageDown</kbd>

for line-up and line-down, respectively.

Comment: I spent at least 30 minutes searching the web for this answer. At no point did it occur to me to actually look in the menu. Oops. Thanks Thomas.

Comment: In this MacBook Pro I don't have `PageUp` or `PageDown` buttons but the same effect is produced for me by using `Fn`-`Up` or `Fn`-`Down`.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of OS X, the shortcut used to be <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>UpArrow</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>DownArrow</kbd>.  If you want this shortcut restored to what you used to use, you can do so in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts.  There, you can create two new shortcuts for the application "Terminal" for menu titles "Line Up" and "Line Down".  This will override the <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PageDown</kbd> default shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

- For `iTerm2` users, you can check / configure keyboard shortcuts for scrolling from menubar at `iTerm2` > `Preferences` > `Keys`
- note that <kbd>Page Up</kbd> is simply <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>up</kbd> in `MacOS`; [ref](https://superuser.com/a/104227/860750) (so <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd> equals <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>up</kbd>)

[image]